# Oauth empty body for token

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, node.js

EDIT: Simple variable misname issue. See my answer below.

I am trying to follow the documentation list here...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm

I am getting stuck on the step 4 and 5. I am using a nodejs express webserver that I have created my own rest endpoint to send my authorization code to which then sends it to salesforce's token endpoint. The problem is the request gives a 200 but with an empty body. I am not sure why there isn't an error code nor a access token. Here is the node js code below for the endpoint.

```
app.get('/sfAuth', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got request for sfAuth");

    var auth_code = req.get("code");
    console.log("auth_code: ", auth_code);

    /* var options = {
        url: "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
        json: {
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "client_secret":"MYSECRET",
            "client_id":"MYCLIENTID",
            "redirect_uri":"MYWEBSITE",
            "code":auth_code
        }
     };
     */

    var options = {
        url: "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYSECRET&code=&"+auth_code+"redirect_uri=MYWEBSITE"
    };


    console.log("Making authorize request to salesforce");

    request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error)
        {
            console.log("Error in making authorize request: ", error);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("successfully got salesforce access token");
            //This below is not the response body but the request which 
            //is very wrong
            //console.log(req.body);
            //res.json(req.body);
            res.json(response.body);
        } 
    });

});//end of sfAuth
```

Also on another note, It says this is supposed to be a post with parameters. I tried both with it in the body and with it as a single url as I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: Can you confirm redirect_uri is same as callback_url what you have defined in your created app's definition?

Comment: Yes because I had the first call to the authorize endpoint with the same redirect_uri and that part works, Question with that, If I am calling the token endpoint from my webserver, is salesforce still going to redirect me again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a simple variable misname/reference. I put comments in the code above to show it. I was referencing the request and not the response from the authorize endpoint.